# Soundex and checking for invalid sound

Tags: sql-server, soundex

Is it ok to check for SQL returning a Soundex of 0000 based on the assumption that it isn't a valid word, e.g. has digits, spaces, special characters or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think soundex is good for that, I think the SOUNDEX() function will omit the digits, spaces and symbol, for example:

```
SELECT SOUNDEX("HELLO")
SELECT SOUNDEX("_HEL123O_")
```

Both give you the same result.

```
H400
```

Besides SOUNDEX() has some [limitation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) in the way it works.

You can take a look at the Levenshtein distance, it determines the number of operations you have to do to make one string exactly like another. You can find an implementation [here](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1680).

HTH